# Infopath View switching is failing on code behind

Tags: infopath

Very complicated InfoPath which logic is mostly in a code behind(sln) is exhibiting failure in view switching when button is clicked. This form works perfectly in development environment(with the same code) and when data connections are configured to production , it is working fine in preview mode. Nonetheless, the view switching fails when form is published as administrator's approved template in the browser?

Please give me some ideas.

The code for switching views is receiving view and view failure but none are being displayed as form only displays previous view without data.

Thanks.

Comment: What error you got? What code u have written for switching view?

Comment: Ok, now that i have looked into the problem, it is not the view switching, rather the form instead of propagating to the view is reopening. I have seen suggestions that it might be the url but to me url looks ok...could there be anything else i need to consider

Answer (score 1):

Provide `&Source` parameter in url. If `&Source` is empty, it will reload form instead of switching view.

Comment: The URL is not an issue & Source exists....